# Generate image from image sprite, css, and php

Tags: php, css, gd, sprite

I have an sprite with a few icons, about 30. I use them by setting the background position of one specific icon. But now, I want to use one icon like a image, to put them for example, in the facebook og:img metatag..

So, how can I generate the icon, by php and GD?

`mydomain.com/generate_icon.php?icon_id=5`

Is there any other way to do this without GD?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use GD?  There is also ImageMagick.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. What do you want to generate from where?

Comment: @Pekka, My read is that he has a large image with 30 sprites within its area, and he wants to extract one and output as a single image.

Comment: @Brad that sounds like a good interpretation, yeah. mauriblint - any specific reason why you can't use GD?

Comment: exactly! I've a big image, this: http://nopagocable.com.ar/images/sprites_icon.png

That I gen with Photoshop.. , my questions is, how can i do this with GD or other method.. sorry for my English!! :)

Comment: I think i do not explain me correctly. Is there any way to take the html content view of the page: ./genererate_icon.php?id=5 and generate a image with this content? Like and screenshot with specific dimensions (100x100) thats will be my icon! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`how can i do this with GD or other method.. sorry for my English!!` here is an example WITH GD

```
$no = isset($_GET['no']) ? $_GET['no'] : 0; <---- Image Number via GET
$img = "sprites.png";
list($h, $w) = getimagesize($img);
$size = ($h < $w) ? $h : $w;

$src = imagecreatefrompng($img);
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size);

imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, ($size * $no), $size, $size);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagegif($dest);
```

Usage `image.php?no=5`

Answer (score 0):

try that: http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ - many options and you can do it in a way you want: `mydomain.com/generate_icon.php?icon_id=5` . An Example of cropping and filtering is looking like that: `<img border="0" src="../phpThumb.php?src=images/loco.jpg&amp;w=300&amp;fltr[]=crop|50&amp;hash=6af23273fc8ec3513eca71d51b018f32" alt="">`